# Cython - include an existing pyd into a new pyd for portablility

Tags: python, cython

I have searched everywhere for an example and I think I might be interpreting the documentation wrong.

I wanted to include the pycrypto Hashing lib into a new Cython pyd file to be used on Windows systems that cannot download / compile pycrypto. After digging through the library I see the using `from Cipher.hash import SHA256`
Calls a SHA256.py, which then does:

```
from Crypto.Util.py3compat import *
from Crypto.Hash.hashalgo import HashAlgo

try:
    import hashlib
    hashFactory = hashlib.sha256

except ImportError:
    from Crypto.Hash import _SHA256
    hashFactory = _SHA256
```

Now the _SHA256 is a pyd, how can i wrap that into a new pyd for portability?

I see in the documentation that I can interface with external headers and wrap those, but what about already compiled?

```
cdef extern from "spam.h":

    int spam_counter

    void order_spam(int tons)
```

Thank you in advance.